# Update other columns after using reordable on a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am currently exploring Filament v3.

Im currently building a table and im using ->reordable('order') on my table and its working just fine.

I would like to know if is there any way to:

- Know which row im grabbing, this is, is there any way i can dump the row that im grabbing and show its info?
- Update other columns on reordering, this is, after my 'order' column is updated is there any way I can also update other columns? For example, I have a column in my db that is called 'succeeding' and it has the id of the succeeding operation. On reordering, I would like to update/swap that column aswell.

Is there any way I can make this work?

I already explored documentation and even tried to play around ->reorderRecordsTriggerAction but I couldn't do or find what I wanted to do. I would like to know if there is a work around this problem.

Comment: you could create trigger on update in your database, if the db you use support these

Comment: @Kazz that was one of the options I thought about it but I was wondering If I really had to go that route or if filament allowed me to do it.